# Cannot checkout git submodules in Azure Pipeline (Within same project)?

Tags: git, azure, azure-pipelines, git-submodules

I have added a git submodule into the main project, which references the sub-project using a relative path. The .gitmodules looks like this:

```
[submodule "Shared"]
path = Shared
url = ../Shared
```

The Azure pipeline is configured to self checkout including the submodules:
File `azure-pipelines.yaml`

[image]

The build-pipeline fails on the checkout step, and gives the following error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l23yB.png)

Extra information:

- Both repositories exist in the same organization and project.
- Both repositories are private.
- I have already checked if disabling the 'Limit job authorizaiton scope' in the organization- and projectsettings worked but unfortunately not.

Any ideas?

Edit: I hid the URLs in the error screenshot, however when I click those I do get a result of the repositories so it definitely exists.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the solution by myself rather quickly after posting this question :).

In the project settings you should disable the YAML pipeline security toggle in order for it to checkout repos within the same project:

[image]